# DIY node server

Tags: express

I am trying to make a node server (like expressJS) from scratch.

My idea is to add callback functions attached to various request handlers as an array with the request url and method as keys.

while receiving a request the appropriate callbacks array is used which uses the forEach method to invoke each callback.

Now this approach worked fine when i tested it with various methods (GET, POST, PUT, ...) and various endpoints.

My question is

Since this approach can handle any number of callbacks given to a method, without the need for a next() function. So what approach is used in expressJS to store multiple callbacks given to any method such that a next() function is needed to invoke the callbacks.

Also what are the drawbacks with my approach.

I am new to this field.

```
const http = require('http')

class MyServer{
    constructor(){
        this.obj = {}
        this.verbsObj = {
            'GET': [],
            'POST': [],
            'PUT': [],
            'DELETE': [],
        }
    }

    get(endpoint, ...args){
        this.verbsObj['GET'].push(...args)
        this.obj[endpoint] = {...this.verbsObj}
    }

    post(endpoint, ...args){
        this.verbsObj['POST'].push(...args)
        this.obj[endpoint] = {...this.verbsObj}
    }

    createServer(){
        const server = http.createServer()
        server.on('request', (req, res) => {
            console.log(this.obj)
            this.obj[req.url][req.method].forEach(cb => {
                cb(req, res)
            })
        })
        return server
    }

    listen(port, hostname, cb){
        this.createServer().listen(port, hostname, cb)
    }

}

const app = new MyServer()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {console.log(req.method, req.url)}, (req, res) => {res.end('Hello World')})
app.post('/', (req, res) => {console.log(req.method, req.url); res.end('post data')})


app.listen(3000, 'localhost', () => {console.log('server running')})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things. I'll refer to callbacks as middlewares:

1. Your middlewares are synchronous. Once you do asynchronous things or code that uses other callbacks, the middlewares for a single method are all executed simultanously.
2. Middlewares in Express and other framework can do things like:

- Change the incoming request.
- Do something with the outgoing response after it's been handled by every middleware.
- Interupt the process and prevent the next middleware from being called.

This will all become apparent once your framework developers a bit beyond the hello world example. Some examples I would suggest you try implement are:

1. A session middleware
2. An authentication middleware
3. A bodyparser middleware
4. A gzip middleware

Once you have these working you'll naturally run into most of the deficiencies with our current setup. I can also highly recommend looking at Koa for a much more pure implementation of middlewares vs. Express' rather messy abstraction.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am new to this field. Other than asynchronous nature of methods,  separate routing and implementation of other methods what other drawbacks does this design have. Also can learning design patterns help make this code industry grade.

Comment: @user17666483 I'm not an AI. I gave you lots of feedback. 'What else?' is not a good follow-up question. I've made my own framework that has middleware support if you're looking for something to study: https://curveballjs.org/

Comment: Sorry, but thanks anyway...

Comment: @user17666483 Assuming this is a study project, which I applaud! It's a great way to understand web frameworks better. I have one general advice.. just try building something with your own framework. You'll see every problem first-hand.